# Unable to Import Xray report to Jira

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, newman, jira-xray

Starting to import results from test.xml
ERROR: Step ‘Xray: Results Import Task’ failed: Unable to confirm Result of the upload..... Upload Failed!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using Xray on Jira Cloud, correct?
If so, then you may have configured your Jira instance incorrectly (due to the endpoint that appears in the log).

If you are in Jira Cloud:

1. configure your Jira instance as a Jira Cloud one][1](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Integration+with+Jenkins#IntegrationwithJenkins-JiraInstance); otherwise, it won't work
2. Make sure that in the [import results task](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Integration+with+Jenkins#IntegrationwithJenkins-Importingtheexecutionresults.1), you are using that instance

Comment: yeah i figured it out next day !! your point is valid Thanks for comment

Comment: great @GPs, I would appreciate if you could mark answer as correct :) thanks!

Comment: @GPs can you please mark the answer as correct? Thanks